# Django template context not showing

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Hi I'm playing around with the template context variable but no matter what I do, the context from current_datetime view function doesn't show up in home.html and there is no error message... What did i do wrong ?

```
#######view.py

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    context = {
        "current_date": now
    }
    return render(request, "current_datetime.html",context)

def home(request):
    title = "My Database"
    context = {
        "template_title": title,
    }
    return render(request,"home.html",context)

#######current_datetime.html

Today is {{ current_date }}

#######home.html

{% extends "base.html" %}
....

{% include 'current_datetime.html' %}

....
```

Comment: What url are you accessing? The one tied to home or the one tied to current_datetime?

Comment: home... the default html..

Comment: What exactly do you mean default.html? The question was 'what is your url'?

Comment: urls route to your views. The view adding current_date to context is not home, but the other one.

Comment: yes i know, but i use the inclusion tag {% include 'current_datetime.html' %}... isn't that supposed to include that in my home.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working because `currenct_date` variable is not in the context of `home` view.

**DRY**

Don't Repeat Yourself. The way you're trying to show date in template, you'll have to pass that variable to every view's context, which totally goes against the DRY principle.

**Use `{% now %}` tag**

Instead of sending current date as a context variable, use the template tag called `{% now %}` which displays date and time in the template. Here's an example:

*current_date.html*

```
Today is {% now "jS F Y H:i" %}
```

Will output:

```
Today is is 3rd September 2015 08:28
```

Here is more on [formatting the output of `now` tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date)

Comment: If I visit current_date.html , it is showing the date, which is fine. But if you look at home.html, I have the inclusion tag {% include 'current_datetime.html %}.. So when I visit home.html, isn't that supposed to show up as well ? the datetime is just an example... What if I use this for other view functions?

Comment: If you use the `{% now %}` tag in *current_date.html* template, it will show up in `home.html` too. But if you're displaying the date using a context variable, it won't show in *home.html* unless `home` view's context has `current_date` variable in it.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But it isn't really what I want to do. I'm just using datetime as an example. Is there a way for me to show 2 view functions in a single page ? Edit: nvm, I did some searching, apparently its not possible. Thanks!